# Add custom buttons to SlickGrid?

Tags: jquery, filter, grid, slickgrid

Any easy API calls for adding custom button to SlickGrid in the header toolbar?

Also, if you could comment how do I get rows, that were filtered or selected via checkboxes via such a button and do some magic and alter data would be welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer to both questions, check the [slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/plugins/slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js) plugin.

You can alter the column header with the `grid.updateColumnHeader(myhtml)` methods, where `myhtml`is some html fragment (including buttons) that you want to insert to the header.

If you want to check the selected rows, just bind to the `grid.onSelectedRowsChanged()` event.

Comment: is it possible to add next/previous custom button or to style them?